# Why do we need a router at home?

Tags: router, wireless-router, switch

From about year 2000 to today, we usually have a router at home, be it Linksys router or TP-Link or Netgear router.

But let's say if we have a Comcast or AT&T U-verse modem, doesn't that do the job of "routing" our requests to the outside world and getting the data back?  Why do we need a "router" inside of our own home?

If the ISP's modem doesn't have 4-ports for us to use, does buying a $30 switch accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Most Cable and DSL Modems actually function as a router.  So the answer to your question, is typically you don't, as these multiple port modems are extremely common with the larger ISPs.

Comment: @Ramhound you write "Most Cable and DSL Modems actually function as a router" OK. So they are routers as well as modems. Router is a function as is modem.    You then write "typically you don't[need a router], as these multiple port modems are extremely common".  But what you write implies(reasonably) that they are routers.

Comment: @barlop - `Gateway` is the more appropriate description of a cable modem that also functions as a router which might or might not have wireless capabilities.  This is certainly what the manufactures of those combined products called them a few years ago.  However, the use of that term, appears to also be a little dated.  Looks like they (stores and manufactures like ARRIS) called just these combined products "cable/dsl modem routers" today

Comment: AT Ramhound  Gateway and router is probably pretty much the same thing, or even simply the same thing. (except that indeed the term 'gateway' is dated as you say), See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1009 "Requirements for Internet Gateways". Obsoleted by https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1812 "Requirements for IP Version 4 Routers".  Manufacturers create a mess with their wild inaccurate networking terminology and what they call things re routers, modems etc, can't be taken that seriously

Comment: You write "If the ISP's modem doesn't have 4-ports for us to use, does buying a $30 switch accomplish the same thing?" <-- Actually a lot of these devices are like a router with 2 ports and a switch connected to one of them internally hence the multiple local ports

Comment: @barlop - Gateway used to refer to these multi-function Cable/DSL modems, while router was simply a router, and a switch was a switch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106206/discussion-between-barlop-and-ramhound).

Comment: AT Ramhound   What year range are you referring to where manufacturer's didn't use the term "router" for those multi-function devices?

Comment: @barlop - I recall the term gateway being used as recently as 2010.

Comment: The gateway term is still very much part of the parlour as far as I can tell (sysadmin by trade). Proving its non-use would be a worthy challenge ;-D

Answer (score 3):

The vendor's modem may or may not build in a router. Many modems (but not all) do include a built-in Router. You can often tell by looking at the modem, if it has 4 Ethernet Ports and Wireless, it includes a built-in router. In this case there is no need to purchase an additional router.

I have had both kinds, and my current modem includes a router.

A router is always needed to convert the external ISP address to your internal IP addressing via NAT in the router. It may be built in, but it is always there.

Check with your ISP which kind you have and what additional equipment (if any) you need.

Comment: what if we get a modem from our ISP that doesn't have a "router" but then we just buy a $30 switch with 4 ports?

Comment: If the modem does not have a router built-in, you must purchase a router. A simple switch will not act as a router. As we have pointed out above, most modems include a router, so please check.

Comment: Router and NAT are different functions. A device that does both would be termed NAT  Router

Comment: NAT was just terminology and not a device. I think most people would understand that easily

Comment: @John NAT is not just terminology, it is a function performed. So is Routing. Look up "NAT Router"  You are acting like "NAT Router" isn't a term. Look it up, see articles about it. A device that does NAT and Routing. Like most consumer "routers".

Comment: @barlop John does a good job of answering the question on the level of which it was asked. I think you’re confusing the matter by misunderstanding the terminology somewhat. ”[NAT] is a method by which IP Addresses are mapped from one realm to another, in an attempt to provide transparent routing to hosts”. Source: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663

Comment: @ErikE Please quote me to show where I said anything that contradicted that. Quote one thing I said that indicates what you think is "confusion". Nothing I wrote contradicts the sentence you quoted. Also I didn't say that he did or didn't do a good job.

Comment: @barlop Not easy to see what your point is.

Comment: @ErikE well you clearly don't care, (if you did then you'd ask some intelligent question to me about what I wrote), but you didn't, and you just presumed things. So don't worry about it then

Answer (score 0):

If your modem is simply a transparent bridging modem and you hook a switch to it, it will work as long as your ISP gives you enough public IPv4 addresses for all your devices. Getting extra public IPv4 addresses usually costs extra per month.

So the standard deal is you get one single public IP address for your household, and most people use a "router" (technically a "NAPT" gateway, but often just called a NAT) so they can use as many private IP addresses as they need on their home network, and the traffic from those devices is translated to look like it comes from the one public IP address when it's sent out to the Internet. So a NAT gateway lets you use a single public IPv4 address to service a whole network of devices.

So what most people call a router doesn't really do any route-finding. It's really just a network address translator to let you use a single public IPv4 address for a whole home network full of devices.

Using a NAT also has a mostly-positive side-effect of acting like a kind of firewall, keeping people on the Internet from making unsolicited connections in to your devices on your home network.

So you could run without a NAT, but you'd have to pay for extra IPv4 addresses, and you'd be less secure.

Some ISPs in some countries do NAT at the ISP level. This is called "Carrier Grade NAT" (CGNAT or just CGN). So they don't even give you a single public IP address. If your ISP does CGNAT, you wouldn't need your own NAT gateway, but you still might want to put some kind of firewall box between your modem and your switch.

Some ISPs will give you a publicly routable IPv6 prefix for no extra charge, which means as many public IPv6 addresses as you could ever need. But since there are still many sites and services that are IPv4-only, you would need the ISP to run "NAT64" to allow your IPv6-only devices to reach IPv4-only services. And you'd still probably want a firewall box between your modem and your switch.

Answer (score 0):

If your modem does not have a built-in router, plugging a switch into it won't work the way you hope. Routers are designed to transfer data from one network to another and also configure devices connected to it with the information it needs to connect to the outside world. In your case, from your home network to your ISPs. Switches are designed to transfer traffic within the same network and do not configure any devices.

If your modem doesn't have a built-in router, you can plug a computer directly into it but it isn't recommended for security reasons and you'll need to configure the computer. What you need to do is purchase a router and connect it to your modem. Most routers come with a 4-port switch built-in and most also include WiFi as well. You can also plug in another switch to the router if you need more ports.

Normal residential equipment and service is assumed in my answer.

More info: https://www.xfinity.com/hub/internet/modem-vs-router

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, a router allows us to establish a private local area network.

Secondly routers allow devices to route packets; communicate via protocols like TCP & IP, contact devices on remote/external networks via the internet, etc.

Switches are less sophisticated and operate at a lower level, dealing with Ethernet frames and such.